# JavaScript Syntax Errors when using external script

Tags: javascript

I have a file named custom.js, and I'm just putting

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
```

In the required places, but I keep getting a syntax here in the console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var m = document.getElementById('customprofile');
var str = "index.php?/profile/1-brandon/";
     if(window.location.href.includes(str)){

        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("class", "none");
        $("body").css({
            "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
        });
        document.getElementById("elProfileTabs_content").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(13, 13, 13, .9)", 
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?      q=tbn:ANd9GcSApUa6V0POxeHbBFzjjtsLhicnFKbQzJgXQgGcHJ_iXu4p8dhHIw')";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "15%";
     }
```

}

Comment: "a syntax here in the console." — What, exactly, does the error message say?

Comment: Check your WebServer, if the response will not provide `Content-Type: text/javascript`, it can breaks. Additional: are you sure, your `custom.js` is stored/uploaded relative to the path? Check your JavaScript-Console: what is the complete response (incl. Header)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing `);` after the last `}` to close the `.ready` function.

Comment: seems to be what it is from what I was looking at as well.